# "truncated" or "partial" discrete time lyapunov equation?

Tags: dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

I am interested in solving the following matrix equation in variable $X$ for known matrices $A,B$:
$$
X + AXA^\top + A^2X(A^\top)^2 + \cdots + A^nX(A^\top)^n = B.\tag{$*$}
$$
Is there a standard approach to solving for $X$?
If $A$ is a stable matrix, is equation ($*)$ related to a Lyapunov equation (detailed below) or an $n$-period approximation of the Lyapunov equation?

---

*Lyapunov equation:*

The discrete time Lyapunov equation in matrix variable $X$ can be written as
$$
A X A^H - X + Q = 0
$$
where $Q$ is Hermitian and $A^H$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$.
If $A$ is a stable matrix, then the solution is given by
$$
X = \sum_{t=0}^\infty A^t Q (A^H)^t.
$$

Comment: You can try the recursive method (as for the Lyapunov equation) , but I fear it will get messy quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about convergence, but perhaps set up an iteration:

$$X_{k+1} = B -  (AX_kA^\top + A^2X_k(A^\top)^2 + \cdots + A^nX_k(A^\top)^n)$$